# Updating my web site with FTP

Tags: ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using FTP to update files on a server](https://superuser.com/questions/270804/using-ftp-to-update-files-on-a-server)

Yesterday I asked how to choose an FTP client to update my website.  The site has a contacts page and it redirects messages left there to our home eMail address.  I've just changed the home eMail ISP and address, so I need to update the contact page.

(I'm a home internet user - not too techy!  I got some helpful answers, mainly recommending FileZilla so far.)

I downloaded the FileZilla Client, entered the web site address, FTP username and password, and up came the files in the right pane under "filename."  I was advised yesterday to right-click on a file and then choose edit, and hunt for where the old eMail address appears.  When I right-click on a file in the second pane down on the right, the list moves up to the top right pane where there isn't a "view/edit" option.  In the second pane down, the "view/edit" option is greyed out.

So where do I look for files to edit, and how do I get to do that?  Do I need to copy to clipboard?  Or what?

Comment: Why not just edit your local copy and copy it to the ftp directory?

Answer (score 1):

To edit files in FileZilla, just right click on the file which you want to edit. It should be in the context menu.

[image]

[image]

However, there is an alternate way:

When I edit my website through FileZilla, I download the file(s) in question to my computer. Once you've got the file downloaded, you can edit it like a regular file. I do it like this so that I can choose the editing program that I want. (Sometimes FileZilla has a default I don't like.)

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, if your struggling to understand how Filezilla works I would suggest using Windows Explorer to connect to your FTP server. That way you can navigate far more easily because I assume you know how to navigate your personal folder on Windows already.

If you are on Windows I would do the following:

1. Goto Start then Run
2. Enter your FTP address i.e. ftp://ftp.domain.com
3. Login using your username and password then click OK
4. You should then be presented with folders as if you were looking at your own hard drive

You should then have either a load of files named index.html etc., or a few folders. Usually you would have a folder named public_html or httpdocs depending on where you are on the server directory structure.

If you can tell us what files you see listed then we can help you further.

Comment: OK I'll try this.  I've got 11 files or folders listed.  the first is called "directory anon_ftp", and when I try to open it, it includes conf, incoming and pub.  Incoming looks promising, and when I open that it includes directory quotadir.

Comment: Have any of the folders got a file called index.html in?

Comment: No.  They're anon, cgi-bin, conf, error_docs, httpdocs,

Comment: httpdocs is the one you want. It should have a few .html files in there.